# Why the time doesn't elapsed in python in some cases?

Tags: python, time, elapsedtime

I run the following python code:

```
>>> time(),5==25/5,time()
(1508830844.2450676, True, 1508830844.2450676)
>>>
```

It seems that the time doesn't elapsed, however using explicit sleep

```
>>> time(),sleep(1),time()
(1508830151.232, None, 1508830152.246)
>>>
```

or using longer tasks

```
>>> time(),[xi for xi in range(1000000) if xi == 100000],time()
(1508830458.736, [100000], 1508830458.892)
>>>
```

behaves as expected, the time has been elapsed.

What is the phenomenon? When I should expect positive result of difference of two time() stamp?
(Tested with python 2.7 and 3.5)

Comment: "Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second" - From the official documentation on time. So, this could merely be a system issue.

Comment: Try the `timeit` module.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are putting all expressions on the same line, with a an expression that has been constant folded; the division is not calculated between the `time()` calls:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('time(),5==25/5,time()', '', 'single'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (time)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (5.0)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (time)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             14 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             16 PRINT_EXPR
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Those `LOAD_CONST` calls and the `COMPARE_OP` take hardly any time at all.

Next, the `time()` clock probably doesn't have the resolution required to capture the short amount of time those 3 opcodes inbetween take. From the [`time.time()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time):

> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second.

Pick a [higher-resolution clock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock_getres). Or you could use the [`timeit.default_timer()` callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer), which should be set to the highest-resolution timer for your platform:

```
>>> from timeit import default_timer
>>> default_timer(), 5==25/5, default_timer()
(352821.948302353, True, 352821.948304896)
```

If you wanted to run time trials on snippets of Python code, to compare their performance, say, then you should be using the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) anyway.